# How to maintain order of insertion of keys when loading file into yaml?

Tags: python, dictionary, yaml, pyyaml

I am trying to use YAML for a python script. The YAML file I have written resembles this:

```
1:
  name: apple
  price: 5
3:
  name: orange
  price: 6
2:
  name: pear
  price: 2
```

When I load the YAML file using `yaml.load` the dictionary is sorted by the keys so it appears in order 1,2,3. How do I maintain the order 1,3,2?

Comment: Dictionaries in Python do not respect your original order, and will not keep a specific order. If you want an order dictionary, use an OrderedDict.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the YAML specification it is explicitly stated that mapping keys have no order. In a file however they have. If you want a simple way to solve this replace PyYAML with [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml/) (disclaimer: I am the author of that package, which is a superset of PyYAML) and use `round_trip_load()`, it will give you ordered dictionaries without the hassle of using single mapping item sequence elements that you need for specifying ordered dicts the "official" way.

```
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
1:
  name: apple
  price: 5
3:
  name: orange
  price: 6
2:
  name: pear
  price: 2
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)
for key in data:
    print(key)
```

gives

```
1
3
2
```

BTW PyYAML doesn't sort by the keys, that ordering is just a side-effect of calculating hashes and inserting integer keys `1`, `2` , `3` in python `dict`s.

Comment: Is ruamel.yaml available for windows or linux only?

Comment: As the categories on PyPI indicate, it is OS independent. I primarily test and develop on Linux however, but I know from others that they use it on Windows and MacOS.

Comment: I have successfully installed ruamel but get an error that it is expecting <document start> but found <scalar> due to the """/ line found at the top of the file. What is the cause of this?

Comment: The `"""` starts a multiline python string, which is useful if you want the file contents to be part of a program. You should however not put that into a YAML file, just use the file you have with the contents in your questionwith `data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(open('your_file_name.yaml'))`